# How do I implement a iframe Element Selector? (As in chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to get an iframe to have a Element Selector, like the one featured in google chrome. I have had no luck finding results online but some of my ideas so far is to possibly create a script which creates temporary click events listeners and remove any hrefs so it does not redirect. This might be a little bit performance taxing though, considering that this will need a large amount of replacements and click events.

This is what I am trying to implement into the iframe : 
[image]

Except without the inpector itself, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can modify the content of the iframe, you could add a click event listener to the entire document that gets the target being clicked and prevents the default action. You can then use the target, and style it or display information about it.

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // now that you have the target and you've prevented
    // the default action such as redirecting to a href,
    // you can style the target or do whatever you want
    // to it.
    target.classList.add ( "selected" );

}, false );
```

This should not be performance taxing.

If you cannot modify the contents of the iframe, but the iframe's content is from the same domain as the parent page, you can still target the iframe's document using jQuery functions. You would add the event listener above like so:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe-id');
var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframe_doc.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
    ...
```

If the iframe's contents do not come from the parent page's domain then you will run into an error caused by the cross-domain policy. You can get around this by using a server side proxy, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

---

The question is *very* broad, but this may help you get started.